# How do i implement Searching with Tags which are in magazine's array(Tags[]) with ransack and pg_search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, ransack, pg-search

I'd like to use ransack and pg_search to do searches on a model.
I have magazine_controller in which i have implemented index function for searching functionalities.It is working for title of magazine but i want to do this for magazine tags. So i can search magazine through magazine's title and magazine's tags in this.i have used ruby on rails for this.
these is code which i have done.
This is magazines_controller.rb

```
def index
    
    authorize! :admin_index, Magazine
    @search = Magazine.search(title_cont: params[:q])
    @magazines = @search.result(distinct: true)

    @magazines = @magazines.order('updated_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(16)
  end
```

This is magazine.rb

include PgSearch

```
  pg_search_scope :literally_matching,
    :against => [:title],
    :using => {
    :tsearch => {:dictionary => "simple"}
    }
```

This is index.html.erb

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <div class="input-group col-md-12">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="<%= params[:q]%>" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
```

there is array of tags in magazine table.
So what should i write for searching through magaznie's tags and title of magazine.